# Repetitive code due to inserting similar objects

Tags: javascript

I'm making a weather app and I need to insert weather icons for 4 different points of the forecast. The code for each icon is pretty much the same except I call `pickIcon` method on each of them. This method just returns the relative path of an svg icon based on the weather status passed to the method.

Is there a way to make this code less repetitive? Or am I overthinking this? I'm not sure if this kind of thing is considered good practice since I'm fairly new to programming. Thanks!

```
const icons = document.querySelector('.today-icons');
const icon600 = document.createElement('object'),
      icon1200 = document.createElement('object'),
      icon1800 = document.createElement('object'),
      icon2200 = document.createElement('object');

    icon600.className = 'weather-icon col col-3';
    icon1200.className = 'weather-icon col col-3';
    icon1800.className = 'weather-icon col col-3';
    icon2200.className = 'weather-icon col col-3';

    icon600.type = 'image/svg+xml';
    icon1200.type = 'image/svg+xml';
    icon1800.type = 'image/svg+xml';
    icon2200.type = 'image/svg+xml';

    icon600.data = `${this.pickIcon(weatherStatus600)}`;
    icon1200.data = `${this.pickIcon(weatherStatus1200)}`;
    icon1800.data = `${this.pickIcon(weatherStatus1800)}`;
    icon2200.data = `${this.pickIcon(weatherStatus2200)}`;

    icons.appendChild(icon600);
    icons.appendChild(icon1200);
    icons.appendChild(icon1800);
    icons.appendChild(icon2200);
```

Comment: Yes, as soon as you see repeated code it's certainly an area you will want to look at.  A simple solution would be to use an array, and iterate this.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let data = [weatherStatus600, weatherStatus1200, weatherStatus1800, weatherStatus2200];
const icons = document.querySelector('.today-icons');

for(const d of data) {
  const icon = document.createElement('object');
  icon.className = 'weather-icon col col-3';
  icon.type = 'image/svg+xml';
  icon.data = `${this.pickIcon(d)}`;
  icons.appendChild(icon);
}
```

This should work!

Comment: `icons` shouldn't be defined inside the loop.

Comment: `for(d of data) {`   Don't forget to define `d`,. -> `for(const d of data) {`

Comment: I've not encountered `for ... of` loops yet but this makes sense. Thanks guys.

Comment: Use for...in for objects and for...of for arrays!